# Nfs Hanged suddenly not able to restart service

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nfs, syslog, iostat

Nfs Hanged suddenly ! Not able to even restart service  :

```
# /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
 * Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                                                                                  [ OK ] 
 * Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                                            [ OK ] 
 * Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting NFS kernel daemon                                                                                                         ^C
```

Syslogs says nfs is blocked for more than 120sec. How to understand the logs ? what has gone wrong here ?

```
# cat  /var/log/syslog | grep nfs
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248354] INFO: task nfsd:2318 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248363] nfsd            D 0000000000000000     0  2318      2 0x00000000
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248406]  [<ffffffffa02a28c0>] ? nfsd_proc_getattr+0xa0/0xa0 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248418]  [<ffffffffa02a3c11>] nfsd_vfs_write.isra.13+0x81/0x3b0 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248422]  [<ffffffffa02bf691>] ? lookup_clientid+0x51/0x80 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248426]  [<ffffffffa02bf766>] ? nfsd4_lookup_stateid+0xa6/0xc0 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248429]  [<ffffffffa02a7773>] nfsd_write+0x93/0x110 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248433]  [<ffffffffa02b2281>] nfsd4_write+0x1b1/0x250 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248437]  [<ffffffffa02b35ca>] nfsd4_proc_compound+0x56a/0x7c0 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248440]  [<ffffffffa029fd2b>] nfsd_dispatch+0xbb/0x200 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248455]  [<ffffffffa029f71f>] nfsd+0xbf/0x130 [nfsd]
Sep  4 10:02:11 InksedgeDev kernel: [2427120.248458]  [<ffffffffa029f660>] ? nfsd_destroy+0x80/0x80 [nfsd]
```

Output of Iostat :

```
# iostat 5 5
Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (InksedgeDev)   09/04/2015  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.68    0.00    0.48    0.25    0.01   93.58

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap1            3.63        15.71        82.80   38138709  201066916
xvdb              0.01         0.05         0.01     119271      15231
xvdc              0.01         0.05         0.01     112329      14600
xvdf              4.25       155.14       175.05  376748353  425087092
md0               0.02         0.10         0.01     231288      29831

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.30    0.00    0.20   49.75    0.00   49.75

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap1            0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
xvdb              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
xvdc              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
xvdf              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
md0               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

What might be the reason ? how to troubleshoot ?

Comment: I rebooted n got the solution but want to know what was the reason